# Add DATE and TIME to RSS FEED - Android

Tags: android, date, time, rss

I have an rss feed with 3 tabs, every tab fetches rss from a link. the rss is working properly but I want to add DATE and TIME below every feed in this part of [pictureLINK](http://postimg.org/image/jfi2s0i4h/), and make it like this [pictureLINK](http://postimg.org/image/5str952xn/). Can anyone help me please.

Here is my full code:

RssTabsActivity.java

```
  public class RssTabsActivity extends TabActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rss_tabs);
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    Intent artIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, RssChannelActivity.class);
    artIntent.putExtra("rss-url", "http://www1.up.edu.ph/index.php/feed/");
    String artTabName = getResources().getString(R.string.tab_art);
    TabSpec artTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(artTabName)

.setIndicator(artTabName, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rss_tab_art))

.setContent(artIntent);
    tabHost.addTab(artTabSpec);
    Intent techIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, RssChannelActivity.class);
    techIntent.putExtra("rss-url", "http://www1.up.edu.ph/index.php/feed/");
    String techTabName = getResources().getString(R.string.tab_tech);
    TabSpec techTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(techTabName)

.setIndicator(techTabName, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rss_tab_tech))

.setContent(techIntent);
    tabHost.addTab(techTabSpec);
    Intent sportsIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, RssChannelActivity.class);
    sportsIntent.putExtra("rss-url", "http://www1.up.edu.ph/index.php/feed/");
    String sportsTabName = getResources().getString(R.string.tab_sports);
    TabSpec sportsTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(sportsTabName)

.setIndicator(sportsTabName, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rss_tab_sports))

.setContent(sportsIntent);
    tabHost.addTab(sportsTabSpec);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
}

}
```

RssChannelActivity.java

```
public class RssChannelActivity extends Activity {

private RssChannelActivity local;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rss_channel);
    String rssUrl = (String)getIntent().getExtras().get("rss-url");
    local = this;
    GetRSSDataTask task = new GetRSSDataTask();
    task.execute(rssUrl);
}
private class GetRSSDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<RssItem> > {
    @Override
    protected List<RssItem> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            RssReader rssReader = new RssReader(urls[0]);
            return rssReader.getItems();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("RssChannelActivity", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<RssItem> result) {

        ListView itcItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rssChannelListView);

        ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>
        (local,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
        itcItems.setAdapter(adapter);
        itcItems.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener(result, local));
    }
}

}
```

RssItem.java

```
public class RssItem {

private String title;

private String link;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return title;
}

}
```

ListListener.java

```
public class ListListener implements OnItemClickListener {

List<RssItem> listItems;

Activity activity;

public ListListener(List<RssItem> aListItems, Activity anActivity) {
    listItems = aListItems;
    activity  = anActivity;
}
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(listItems.get(pos).getLink()));

    activity.startActivity(i);

}

 }
```

RssParseHandler.java

```
public class RssParseHandler extends DefaultHandler {

private List<RssItem> rssItems;

private RssItem currentItem;

private boolean parsingTitle;

private StringBuffer currentTitleSb;

private boolean parsingLink;

public RssParseHandler() {
    rssItems = new ArrayList<RssItem>();
}

public List<RssItem> getItems() {
    return rssItems;
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes               
    attributes) throws SAXException {
    if ("item".equals(qName)) {
        currentItem = new RssItem();
    } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
        parsingTitle = true;

        currentTitleSb = new StringBuffer();
    } else if ("link".equals(qName)) {
        parsingLink = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws
     SAXException   {
    if ("item".equals(qName)) {
        rssItems.add(currentItem);
        currentItem = null;
    } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {

        parsingTitle = false;

        if (currentItem != null) {
            // Set item's title here
            currentItem.setTitle(currentTitleSb.toString());
        }

    } else if ("link".equals(qName)) {
        parsingLink = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    if (parsingTitle) {
        if (currentItem != null) {

            currentTitleSb.append(new String(ch, start, length));
        }
    } else if (parsingLink) {
        if (currentItem != null) {
            currentItem.setLink(new String(ch, start, length));
            parsingLink = false;
        }
    }
}

}
```

RssReader.java

```
public class RssReader {

private String rssUrl;

public RssReader(String rssUrl) {
    this.rssUrl = rssUrl;
}
public List<RssItem> getItems() throws Exception {
    // SAX parse RSS data
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

    RssParseHandler handler = new RssParseHandler();

    saxParser.parse(rssUrl, handler);

    return handler.getItems();
}
}
```

RssTabsLayout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".RssTabsActivity" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_art"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_tech"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_sports"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>


</RelativeLayout>
```

RssChannelLayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/rssChannelListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom ArrayAdapter:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RssItem> {

  private final List<RssItem> aListItems
  private final Activity context;

  public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<RssItem> aListItems) {
    super(context, R.layout.yourcustomlayout, aListItems);
    this.context = context;
    this.aListItems = aListItems;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
      view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.yourcustomlayout, null);
      final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
      viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
      viewHolder.time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time);
      view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
      view = convertView;
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.text.setText(aListItems.get(position).getName());
    holder.time.setText(aListItems.get(position).getTime());
    return view;
  }


  static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text;
    protected TextView time;
  }
}
```

Your Custom XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/title"
    android:textSize="30px" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/time"
    android:textSize="30px" >
</TextView>
```

Comment: I got error in         holder.time.setChecked(aListItems.get(position).getTime());               It says "The method setChecked(String) is undefined for the type TextView"

Comment: hey @ssrikanth-gr I got error in this line      holder.time.setChecked(aListItems.get(position).getTime());     It says "The method setChecked(String) is undefined for the type TextView"

Comment: hey Can I use something other that setChecked?

Comment: @ssrikanth-gr but still not working :( No errors but the date and time still wont show up. :(

Comment: @ssrikanth-gr I don't understand it. can you just help me with my code please. :'(